# Unable to read excel file which was earlier read just fine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been using python 3.7+ and pandas' read_excel() function to read different excel files into Spyder IDE. All was working fine for months. However, all of sudden and out of nowhere, I started getting file not found error messages. Codes that were previously working fine, have also started producing same error, even though the files are there. To debug, I created a simple test excel file with name temp.xlsx and tried reading it using following command,

```
In: pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx')
```

However, I am getting this error even though file is there,

```
Out: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-8b141d361f1e>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 307, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 394, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp.xlsx'
```

Any help and ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the file in the same directory?. **Try giving full address of the excel file.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy paste your temp.xlsx file to the same folder that contains your python code.

OR,

pd.read_excel("Full address to the file")

Comment: providing full address worked for me, although it was working with relative address before

Answer (score 0):

I tried reading my xlsx file and it works. I also have python3.7
Downloaded xlsx file from here

#### FILE-DOWNLOAD

https://github.com/irJERAD/Intro-to-Data-Science-in-Python/blob/master/MyNotebooks/scimagojr-3.xlsx

#### CODE

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('~/python_data_analytics/data-files/scimagojr-3.xlsx')
df.head()
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Rank    Country Documents   Citable documents   Citations   Self-citations  Citations 
per document    H index
0   1   China   127050  126767  597237  411683  4.70    138
1   2   United States   96661   94747   792274  265436  8.20    230
2   3   Japan   30504   30287   223024  61554   7.31    134
3   4   United Kingdom  20944   20357   206091  37874   9.84    139
4   5   Russian Federation  18534   18301   34266   12422   1.85    57
```